# Width changed in JS but not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

so I have set up my div to expand on href click. Href is before div which is executing my javascript width of div from 48px to 240px. So all is working properly but when the width is expanded and I click on area where div has been expanded it doesn't collapses. Can't figure out how to fix it. On Code Snippet seems working but on my browser doesn't work (Firefox).

```js
function toggleNavbar() {
     
    var navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');

    var displaySetting = navbar.style.width;

    var navbarButton = document.getElementById('navbar_button');

    if (displaySetting == '240px') {
      navbar.style.width = '48px';
      document.getElementById('navigation').innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-bars'></i>";
    }
    else {
      navbar.style.width = '240px';
      document.getElementById('navigation').innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-bars'></i> Navigation";
    }
  }
```

```css
#navbar {
    position: relative;
    width: 48px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

#navbar .navbar_item {
    background-color: rgb(165, 23, 69);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

#navbar .navbar_item i {
    width: 30px;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7204bf25d6.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
    <a href="#" id="navbar_button" onclick="toggleNavbar()">
        <div class="navbar_item" id="navigation">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working for me in this snippet in firefox...

Comment: Yeah for me too. But on my domain is not.. @ikiK

Comment: Maybe you have a element overlapping it, try to set z-index to higher. Or add click event listener and check if it fires at all at that spot.

Comment: Did it, seems like only text is clickable but I have set up entire div to be clickable i think? @ikiK

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed.

I haven't added jQuery to my documents. After adding it it has fixed problem.

Thanks to @ikiK for giving some advice on checking code.